# I can't make a table in roblox that there should be point lights (there are in each other part)

Tags: lua, roblox

So i tried to make a multiple manipulation of pointlight properties but it doesn't work

```
for i, Part in pairs(parts) do
    if Part:IsA("BasePart") then
        local light = Part:FindFirstChild("PointLight")
        if light and light:IsA("PointLight") then
            table.insert(lights, light) -- doesn't put pointlight in the table
        end
    end
end 
function LightsOff(lights)
    for b, light in pairs(lights) do
        light.Enabled = false -- do stuff
    end
end

function LightsOn(lights)
    for y, light in pairs(lights) do
        light.Enabled = true -- do stuff
    end
end
```

I expected the pointlights to enable/disaible on function call but the problem is table expected, got nil

Comment: Where are the `lights` and `parts` tables defined?

Comment: They are defined ealier also normally lights table is nil

Answer (score 0):

The error `table expected got nil` shows up anywhere an undefined table is passed into a table function, like `pairs` or `table.insert`.

Without the full error message, it could be on the first line `for i, Part in pairs(parts) do` or it could be `table.insert(lights, light)`, or anywhere you call `LightsOn` or `LightsOff`. All of these places could be making the same mistake, not defining their tables.

So try this :

```lua
-- get the lights
local lights = {}
local parts = game.Workspace:GetDescendants()

for i, part in ipairs(parts) do
    if part:IsA("PointLight") then
        table.insert(lights, part)
    end
end
```